# Laravel Error: Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laragon

I have clone my project in to **C:\laragon\www**, I'm running the command `composer update`, but I am getting this error, Does any have this error before?

I have tried some other stackoverflow solutions but are not work for me.

Comment: Which is "this error"? The one from the question's title is not related to Composer after all

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check if youre **Laravel** and **PHP** versions from your project are equal on **Laragon**.

Then you could try using this commands in **Laragon's terminal**.

```
composer clearcache
rm -rf vendor/*
composer install
```